# Redirect echos of Windows batch-file commands

Tags: batch-file, echo, command-prompt

The default behavior of the Windows command prompt when executing a `.bat` file (if `echo OFF` is not specified) is to `echo` each command in the script before running it. For example, if I create a file `example.bat` with contents

> ```
> ver
> vol
> ```

then running the script produces the following content in the command window:

> ```
> C:\test>example.bat
>
> C:\test>ver
>
> Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.XXXXX.XXX]
>
> C:\test>vol
>  Volume in drive C is Local Disk
>  Volume Serial Number is XXXX-XXXX
>
> C:\test>
> ```

If I alter the contents of my script to redirect one of the commands to a file, e.g.

> ```
> ver>example.log
> vol
> ```

then the *output* of the command (`Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.XXXXX.XXX]`) is redirected to the log file, but the *echo of the input* (`C:\test>ver`) is still printed to the command prompt window as before. Is there a way I can redirect that echoed command to the log file instead, in the same way the output is being redirected?

Note that I still want the echo and the output of the second command (`vol`) printed to the command prompt window as before. So simply echoing the execution of the batch script itself to the log file doesn't do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible way is the following:

```cmd
@rem /* The main section of the script here is not echoed due to `@`;
@rem    the actual commands to be echoed are placed in a sub-routine,
@rem    which is called here; the call is then redirected to a file: */
@call :SUB > "file.log"
@rem // This command and its output are echoed to the console:
vol
@rem // The script needs to be quit here not to execute the rest again:
@exit /B

:SUB
@rem // This command is subject to the redirection of the call:
ver
```